# WildFly not loading MySQL driver

Tags: mysql, eclipse, jdbc, wildfly, driver

There's been a few questions on this already, but, after trying the solutions (mainly adding through .cli), I'm still unable to these two to work together.  Wildfly serves servlets and JSPs w/o db access, and running the class as an application connects to database just fine.  IDE is latest (tried to use the latest of everything), Eclipse 2019-12.

standalone.xml [excerpt]:

```
   <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:5.0">
        <datasources>
            <drivers>
                <driver name="mysql" module="com.mysql">
                    <driver-class>com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
                </driver>
            </drivers>
        </datasources>
    </subsystem>
```

module.xml:

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.5" name="com.mysql">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar" />
    </resources>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

directory:

```
wildfly-18.0.1.Final/modules/system/layers/base/com/mysql/main/
  module.xml
  mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar
```

console log:

```
14:09:53,952 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.9.1.Final
14:10:03,718 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.4.11.Final
14:10:03,778 INFO  [org.jboss.threads] (main) JBoss Threads version 2.3.3.Final
14:10:04,768 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0049: WildFly Full 18.0.1.Final (WildFly Core 10.0.3.Final) starting
14:10:12,285 INFO  [org.wildfly.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 28) ELY00001: WildFly Elytron version 1.10.4.Final
14:10:29,689 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute 'security-realm' in the resource at address '/core-service=management/management-interface=http-interface' is deprecated, and may be removed in a future version. See the attribute description in the output of the read-resource-description operation to learn more about the deprecation.
14:10:29,969 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 29) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute 'security-realm' in the resource at address '/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/https-listener=https' is deprecated, and may be removed in a future version. See the attribute description in the output of the read-resource-description operation to learn more about the deprecation.
14:10:30,352 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYDS0004: Found argh.war in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called argh.war.dodeploy
14:10:30,356 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYDS0004: Found BackToTech.war in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called BackToTech.war.dodeploy
14:10:30,557 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0039: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
14:10:30,739 INFO  [org.xnio] (MSC service thread 1-5) XNIO version 3.7.3.Final
14:10:30,795 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] (MSC service thread 1-5) XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.7.3.Final
14:10:31,036 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.microprofile.opentracing] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) WFLYTRACEXT0001: Activating MicroProfile OpenTracing Subsystem
14:10:31,044 WARN  [org.jboss.as.txn] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72) WFLYTX0013: The node-identifier attribute on the /subsystem=transactions is set to the default value. This is a danger for environments running multiple servers. Please make sure the attribute value is unique.
14:10:31,075 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 51) WFLYCLINF0001: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
14:10:31,076 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.microprofile.config.smallrye._private] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) WFLYCONF0001: Activating WildFly MicroProfile Config Subsystem
14:10:31,102 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 64) WFLYNAM0001: Activating Naming Subsystem
14:10:31,088 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 70) WFLYSEC0002: Activating Security Subsystem
14:10:31,137 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.microprofile.health.smallrye] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 61) WFLYHEALTH0001: Activating Eclipse MicroProfile Health Subsystem
14:10:31,251 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.microprofile.metrics.smallrye] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) WFLYMETRICS0001: Activating Eclipse MicroProfile Metrics Subsystem
14:10:31,483 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 74) WFLYWS0002: Activating WebServices Extension
14:10:31,533 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYNAM0003: Starting Naming Service
14:10:31,581 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYMAIL0001: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
14:10:31,602 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSEC0001: Current PicketBox version=5.0.3.Final
14:10:31,886 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jsf] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) WFLYJSF0007: Activated the following JSF Implementations: [main]
14:10:32,033 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYJCA0009: Starting JCA Subsystem (WildFly/IronJacamar 1.4.17.Final)
14:10:32,198 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 43) WFLYJCA0005: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver (version 8.0)
14:10:32,524 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = mysql
14:10:33,077 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYUT0003: Undertow 2.0.27.Final starting
14:10:33,697 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 73) WFLYUT0014: Creating file handler for path 'D:\Wildfly\wildfly-18.0.1.Final/welcome-content' with options [directory-listing: 'false', follow-symlink: 'false', case-sensitive: 'true', safe-symlink-paths: '[]']
14:10:35,395 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.io] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 52) WFLYIO001: Worker 'default' has auto-configured to 16 core threads with 128 task threads based on your 8 available processors
14:10:35,423 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYEJB0481: Strict pool slsb-strict-max-pool is using a max instance size of 128 (per class), which is derived from thread worker pool sizing.
14:10:35,429 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYEJB0482: Strict pool mdb-strict-max-pool is using a max instance size of 32 (per class), which is derived from the number of CPUs on this host.
14:10:35,624 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYUT0012: Started server default-server.
14:10:35,629 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYUT0018: Host default-host starting
14:10:35,659 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBoss Remoting version 5.0.15.Final
14:10:35,992 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jaxrs] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 53) WFLYRS0016: RESTEasy version 3.9.1.Final
14:10:36,167 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTP listener default listening on 127.0.0.1:8080
14:10:36,990 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYEJB0493: EJB subsystem suspension complete
14:10:54,296 INFO  [org.jboss.as.patching] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYPAT0050: WildFly Full cumulative patch ID is: base, one-off patches include: none
14:10:54,365 WARN  [org.jboss.as.domain.management.security] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYDM0111: Keystore D:\Wildfly\wildfly-18.0.1.Final\standalone\configuration\application.keystore not found, it will be auto generated on first use with a self signed certificate for host localhost
14:10:54,378 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYDS0013: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory D:\Wildfly\wildfly-18.0.1.Final\standalone\deployments
14:10:54,511 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "argh.war" (runtime-name: "argh.war")
14:10:54,511 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "BackToTech.war" (runtime-name: "BackToTech.war")
14:10:54,862 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTPS listener https listening on 127.0.0.1:8443
14:10:59,399 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBWS022052: Starting JBossWS 5.3.0.Final (Apache CXF 3.3.3) 
14:11:11,940 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYWELD0003: Processing weld deployment BackToTech.war
14:11:12,271 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYWELD0003: Processing weld deployment argh.war
14:11:16,128 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version] (MSC service thread 1-1) HV000001: Hibernate Validator 6.0.18.Final
14:11:18,903 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.Version] (MSC service thread 1-3) WELD-000900: 3.1.2 (Final)
14:11:18,977 INFO  [org.infinispan.factories.GlobalComponentRegistry] (MSC service thread 1-8) ISPN000128: Infinispan version: Infinispan 'Infinity Minus ONE +2' 9.4.16.Final
14:11:21,513 INFO  [io.smallrye.metrics] (MSC service thread 1-8) MicroProfile: Metrics activated
14:11:21,616 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 78) WFLYCLINF0002: Started client-mappings cache from ejb container
14:11:21,619 INFO  [io.smallrye.metrics] (MSC service thread 1-4) MicroProfile: Metrics activated
14:11:21,714 WARN  [org.jboss.weld.Bootstrap] (MSC service thread 1-8) WELD-000146: BeforeBeanDiscovery.addAnnotatedType(AnnotatedType<?>) used for class com.sun.faces.flow.FlowDiscoveryCDIHelper is deprecated from CDI 1.1!
14:11:21,701 WARN  [org.jboss.weld.Bootstrap] (MSC service thread 1-4) WELD-000146: BeforeBeanDiscovery.addAnnotatedType(AnnotatedType<?>) used for class com.sun.faces.flow.FlowDiscoveryCDIHelper is deprecated from CDI 1.1!
14:11:25,772 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 78) Initializing Mojarra 2.3.9.SP04 for context '/BackToTech'
14:11:25,772 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 79) Initializing Mojarra 2.3.9.SP04 for context '/argh'
14:11:28,411 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 78) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: '/BackToTech' for server 'default-server'
14:11:29,372 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 79) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: '/argh' for server 'default-server'
14:11:29,917 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 44) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "BackToTech.war" (runtime-name : "BackToTech.war")
14:11:29,919 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 44) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "argh.war" (runtime-name : "argh.war")
14:11:30,246 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0212: Resuming server
14:11:30,259 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0060: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
14:11:30,260 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0051: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
14:11:30,262 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0025: WildFly Full 18.0.1.Final (WildFly Core 10.0.3.Final) started in 101259ms - Started 797 of 1022 services (378 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
14:11:36,717 SEVERE [semanticWeb.mysql.ConnectionImpl] (default task-1) null: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost/technology
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:702)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:228)
    at deployment.BackToTech.war//semanticWeb.mysql.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:37)
    at deployment.BackToTech.war//semanticWeb.mysql.ConnectionImpl$ConnectionPool.acquireImpl(ConnectionImpl.java:92)
    at deployment.BackToTech.war//semanticWeb.mysql.ConnPool.aquire(ConnPool.java:34)
    at deployment.BackToTech.war//semanticWeb.mysql.ConnPool.<init>(ConnPool.java:21)
    at deployment.BackToTech.war//semanticWeb.mysql.MysqlPortal.init(MysqlPortal.java:24)
    at deployment.BackToTech.war//semanticWeb.SemanticWeb.initMysql(SemanticWeb.java:96)
    at deployment.BackToTech.war//semanticWeb.SemanticWeb.<init>(SemanticWeb.java:38)
    at deployment.BackToTech.war//server.Server.<init>(Server.java:26)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.2.Final//org.jboss.weld.injection.ConstructorInjectionPoint.newInstance(ConstructorInjectionPoint.java:119)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.2.Final//org.jboss.weld.injection.ConstructorInjectionPoint.invokeAroundConstructCallbacks(ConstructorInjectionPoint.java:92)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.2.Final//org.jboss.weld.injection.ConstructorInjectionPoint.newInstance(ConstructorInjectionPoint.java:78)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.2.Final//org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.AbstractInstantiator.newInstance(AbstractInstantiator.java:28)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.2.Final//org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BasicInjectionTarget.produce(BasicInjectionTarget.java:112)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.2.Final//org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BeanInjectionTarget.produce(BeanInjectionTarget.java:186)
    at org.jboss.as.weld@18.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.weld.injection.WeldInjectionContext.produce(WeldInjectionContext.java:46)
    at org.jboss.as.weld@18.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.weld.injection.WeldManagedReferenceFactory.create(WeldManagedReferenceFactory.java:55)
    at org.jboss.as.ee@18.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.component.ComponentInstantiatorInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentInstantiatorInterceptor.java:67)
    at org.jboss.invocation@1.5.2.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.invocation@1.5.2.Final//org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:53)
    at org.jboss.as.ee@18.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.component.AroundConstructInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(AroundConstructInterceptorFactory.java:26)
    at org.jboss.invocation@1.5.2.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.weld@18.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.weld.injection.WeldInterceptorInjectionInterceptor.processInvocation(WeldInterceptorInjectionInterceptor.java:56)
    at org.jboss.invocation@1.5.2.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.weld@18.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.weld.injection.WeldInjectionContextInterceptor.processInvocation(WeldInjectionContextInterceptor.java:43)
    at org.jboss.invocation@1.5.2.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ee@18.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.concurrent.ConcurrentContextInterceptor.processInvocation(ConcurrentContextInterceptor.java:45)
    at org.jboss.invocation@1.5.2.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.invocation@1.5.2.Final//org.jboss.invocation.ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.processInvocation(ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.java:60)
    at org.jboss.invocation@1.5.2.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.invocation@1.5.2.Final//org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:53)
    at org.jboss.as.ee@18.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.constructComponentInstance(BasicComponent.java:161)
    at org.jboss.as.ee@18.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.constructComponentInstance(BasicComponent.java:134)
    at org.jboss.as.ee@18.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.createInstance(BasicComponent.java:88)
    at org.jboss.as.ee@18.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.component.ComponentRegistry$ComponentManagedReferenceFactory.getReference(ComponentRegistry.java:149)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@18.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$6.createInstance(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1217)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet$DefaultInstanceStrategy.start(ManagedServlet.java:300)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet.forceInit(ManagedServlet.java:212)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain.forceInit(ServletChain.java:130)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:63)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@18.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:132)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@18.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@18.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:269)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:133)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:130)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@18.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@18.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@18.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@18.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@18.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:249)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:99)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:376)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
```

Comment: How is your datasource configured ? Adding a driver in the subsystem is to make it available to WildFly not to your deployment. You would need to add a dependency to the module in your war to have the driver accessible

Comment: That sounds promising in that I was unaware of needing to configure the war directly and likely did not do what you're describing.  I'll read up on how to configure a datasource for deployment, thank you.

Comment: Hooray, works now.  I think the change that made it go was to add the line:  Dependencies: com.mysql   to the file  Manifest.MF under WebContent->Meta-inf        Course, I tweaked several things at once so I'm not certain this was the winning action.  Anyway, thanks ehsavoie for setting me down the right path.